# How can I type ` character when using Chinese input source?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm looking for a way to type in <kbd>`</kbd> character by pressing the top-left key (below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key). This works when I use the English input, but on Chinese input it changes into <kbd>·</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> key gives me `～`.

Is it possible to type in <kbd>`</kbd> even on Chinese input source, using Karabiner-Elements? Or can I achieve it on other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter <kbd>`</kbd> character, even without using Karabiner-Elements.

Just turn on <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and simply press the <kbd>`</kbd> key (The one below the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key), and it will enter <kbd>`</kbd> character, while in Chinese input mode.

Comment: Thanks and it worked, but I found that I must turn off Caps Lock triggering a language switch (between English and Chinese), which for me is far more useful...